# AutoLayout Constraints Across All Devices Mathematically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints, anchor

I am new to IOS Development, please go easy.

I am attempting to create a universal identically positioned `UIView` in the main ViewController of *any* IOS Device (The view will change dynamically and match across all IOS devices (relative to the size of the screen), and not ruin the positioning of the view). Basically, is it possible to mathematically alter the "equalToConstants" in the anchor to create some kind of formula that will yield the same result across all screens using division/multiplication of the main screen size (IPad, IPhone, etc.) to determine an exact similar location visually?

Something like `bottomButtonView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: -/+ 20).isActive = true`

As opposed to a "fixed" variable that yields a different "visual" position across all IOS devices:

```
bottomButtonView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
```

I do not want to use the storyboard, as I am knee-deep in programmatically building my app. I have also heard programmatically programming your app is the way to go for easier future changes etc.

The following snippet of code is showing what I have in the ViewController that displays a red rectangle which would be great to have the same size/shape relative to the screen size (IPad, IPhone 6,7,8,X,11, etc.):

```
let bottomButtonView = UIView()
bottomButtonView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
bottomButtonView.backgroundColor = .red
view.addSubview(bottomButtonView)
bottomButtonView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = false
bottomButtonView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
bottomButtonView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
bottomButtonView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
bottomButtonView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
bottomButtonView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 400).isActive = true
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Some iPads have a 3:4 aspect ratio, and the iPhones are much narrower and taller.  Do you want your red rectangle to always have the same aspect ratio?  If so, what would that be?  The goal shouldn't really be to have the exact same UI on all devices.  For iPhones you want to make use of the vertical space you have.  On iPads, you want to take advantage of the extra width.  Plus, you need to consider supporting the landscape orientation of the iPad.

Comment: The general approach is to use an aspect ratio constraint between your view and the superview/root view, but as @vacawama says, you need to consider what you actually want the vie to look like on various device classes.

Comment: Very good points. I definitely agree, and I did not think of this prior to my post. I definitely want to take advantage of the differing sizes of screens to make it look good across all devices. Follow up question on that, creating a custom view per device seems very time consuming, is there perhaps a direction you could point me in to easily modify/tweak the UI for each individual device as I go? Some sort of identifier code that checks for what device is being used, then "funnels" them toward the custom fit UI for that screen. Or, there is a much better way I am not thinking of fixing this?

Comment: Also as a follow-up question for both of you: You had both mentioned aspect ratios. What would I plug into the above to get a similar result across all devices in the aspect ratio sense for the fixed variable? What would that look like fit into my above block of code? Thanks again, guys.

Comment: For aspect ratio, set the width of the view equal to the height of the view with a multiplier.

Comment: Thank you, @vacawama ! Would you be able to modify the below code to showcase how this is written with the width equal to the height of the view with a multiplier? `bottomButtonView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true`

Comment: `bottomButtonView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomButtonView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 3/4).isActive = true`

Comment: You are a legend! @vacawama Have a great rest of your Sunday afternoon.